# Sql-Server Select into From query

Tags: sql-server

hello i am facing the following challenge:

i am using SQL SERVER and I want to do the following action:

```
SELECT * INTO existingTable
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl);
```

I want to know how is it possible to get query result into a table with
a SQL statement

thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to explain what the problem is. I don't see a question being asked here.

Comment: as I use the following code i get errors regarding ')' even tho it doesn't seem to be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `from` and the (brackets)

```
insert into existingTable 
select * from tbl
```

It would be good practice to explicitly name your columns

```
insert into existingTable (colA, colB, ... )
select col1, col2, ... from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

If the fields between the tables are not the same, you will have to type them out:

```
Insert Into existingTable (field1, field2, field3, ...)
SELECT field1, field2, field3, ... from tbl
```